# To check if $f_x$ and $f$ are bounded for $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$ for$(x,y) \ne(0,0)$

I want to check if $f_x$ and $f$ are bounded

I calculated $f_x=\frac{2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

To check if its bounded below or above,do I have to calculate limits?

If so,at which points?

Comment: I am an amateur at this, so I don't know what $f_x$ is. Could somebody please tell me?

Comment: Its partial derivative of $f$ wrt $x$

Comment: I assume that *wrt* means "with respect to", and now it makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view $f(x,x)=\frac{x^3}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{2}x$, hence it is unbounded, if $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$

Edit: Your $f_x$ is correct. You can show that it is bounded by calculating the maximum and minimum.